# Is there any in Place Editable Syntax Highlighter free or paid control for ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio

I'm in a team and we are building CMS in ASP.NET 4.0 using C#,
It is very good CMS and expect to start using it soon, but I need a control where users can insert html, css, js, xml and code Syntax and it show them colorful Syntax where the also can edit this Syntax in place with out loosing the colors and Syntax format, line numbers and alignment and if I'm not asking too much with intellisense at like Visual Studio editing at run time ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) : Syntax highlighter and editor.

Comment: I think this is great, I'll try to use this and create ASP.NET control from it, but I need more for intellisense if there is any